# How can I use PHP variables within a WP_Query array?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to pull variables into a WP_Query array, but the intended output isn't what I would expect.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$country_name = the_title();
$populate_jhcarousel = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'story',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'location',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => "'"$country_name"'"
            ),
        ),
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'order'=> 'DESC'
        )  );
?>
```

My intention is to bring in all posts whose location is the title of whatever country page their on. In my local setup, I'm testing with Tanzania. When I use the following `'terms' => 'Tanzania'`, my slider populates properly. But when I use the variable, it either throws a 500 error, or just outputs the word "Tanzania" in place of my slider. Below is what I've tried, and the results:

`'terms' => "'"$country_name"'"` = HTTP ERROR 500

`'terms' => '$country_name'` = "Tanzania"

`'terms' => $country_name` = "Tanzania"

`'terms' => 'Tanzania'` = Intended result

Any help on using variables within a WP_Query array would be welcomed. Many thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: you get a htrp 500 error because you need to add concatenation operator "." (dot).

Comment: more accurately, he needs to realize the quotes and concat are not necessary. just do `'terms' => $country_name`

Comment: @Dexter0015 would you mind elaborating on your solution? I've tried `'terms' => .$country_name.` and I've tried `'terms' => '.$country_name.'` and finally `'terms' => "'".$country_name."'"` all without my intended result.

@KaiQing I've also tried your suggestion, as I stated above.

Comment: @AlexRobinson In the op, you wrote that you used `'terms' => "'"$country_name"'"`, which is missing the concatenation dots between the double quotes and `$country_name`.  As @KaiQing said, you don't need quotes.  If `$country_name` is a string, it should work.  Try outputting and checking that `$country_name` is correctly set before hand.

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you are using `the_title()`, which has the default behavior of echoing out the title.  Change that to `get_the_title()` and see if that works.

Comment: @DanielFoust—You beautiful genius! That worked!

Comment: Yeah I didnt catch that one but daniel is right. the_title() is an echo function. get_the_title() is a return function and that's what you want here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `the_title()`, which has the default behavior of echoing out the title. Change that to `get_the_title()`.